# How I Determine The latest OpenSSL patch is installed?

Tags: software-installation, openssh

This post is about applying the latest patch for OpenSSL to protect our port 443 web traffic, not using ssh to log into these systems.

I went and obtained the lastest OpenSSL tarball source patch `openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz` from [here](http://www.openssl.org/source/) for my Linux workstation running CentOS 6.5, and built the patch, including

`./config; make; make test; make install # as root`

This installed in `/usr/local/ssl`.

I wanted to prove the patch out in a safe place, before applying it to our production systems. However, after running everything, I'm stumped. The

`./config, make, make test, and make install`

steps completed without errors.

How do I check that the latest OpenSSL is installed?

Here is the result of testing version from various answers:

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Tue Apr  8 02:33:43 UTC 2014
platform: linux-elf
```

Comment: I see 2 down-votes for this question. It would be better if people let the OP know why they are down-voting the question, so that the OP can make his question more better.  For me, it seems a good question only :)

Comment: @Ramesh Good observation.  Perhaps the downvotes are from people who've *presumed* `ssh` is never dynamically linked to `libssl`?

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks', can't we make it mandatory to provide comments in case if someone is down-voting an answer? If someone is downvoting my question, I need to know what caused them to downvote. I am not saying they should not down-vote. If they provide the reason, it will give me an opportunity to fix the question and make it better. After all, we need better quality in the site :)

Comment: @Ramesh : I think you'd have to get that past the S.E. staff.  Personally I disagree (you should be allowed to up/down vote anonymously, although it some cases you're right: it is not constructive without a comment). I think the only mandatory comment should be for the *first close vote.*

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks', agreed :)

Comment: I noticed today that openssl is a little unusual in that it 1) installs into its own, out of tree subdirectory, 2) does not build the shared library by default. **This last point is important**, because without that things that link dynamically will still be using the old one.  I recommend you rebuild and install with `./config --prefix=/usr/local shared` and delete the `/usr/local/ssh` directory (or read the edit at the beginning of my answer).

Comment: Thanks. I did this. I first deleted /usr/local/ssh, and then configured with the prefix. It's about getting openssl version to use the new ssl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Preamble:** As observed in the question, openssl installs by default into `/usr/local/ssl`.  My recommendation is to use `./config --prefix=/usr/local shared` (notice the space before "shared") so that it installs there (and builds the shared library, `libssl`), rather than its own private subdirectory.  If you do not do this, you will have to add a file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with `/usr/local/ssl/lib` in it (see below for the significance of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` files), and add `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH`.

---

You will need to run `ldconfig` after `make install` to add the libraries to the linker cache.  If that doesn't work, read on.

`make install` probably by default went to `/usr/local`, which *should* take precedence but may not.  You can thus leave your distro's openssl install to avoid messing around with the package manager and prereqs, but still use your own locally built version as the default.  To check:

```
ldd $(which ssh) | grep libssl
```

If you get no output, your `ssh` was statically linked and needs to be rebuilt (see Anton's answer). Otherwise, this should point to your `/usr/local` version.  If it points to something else:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libssl
```

The `/usr/local` version should be shown, but after some other one.  If so, skip down to "/usr/local/lib does not have precedence" below. If not, make sure `/usr/local` is in the linker path generally:

```
ldconfig -p | grep "/usr/local"
```

If not, `grep -r "/usr/local" /etc/ld.so.conf.d`.  If that is not there, add a file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` called `00-local.conf` with one line:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Run `ldconfig` (no switches) and go through this again.

---

## /usr/local/lib does not have precedence

Find the linker cache config file where the path is added:

```
grep -r "/usr/local" /etc/ld.so.conf.d
```

If it's not there, you'll have to add a file as explained above.  Presuming it is, the problem is the files are processed lexicographically. E.g., if the content of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` is:

```
addtheselibraries.conf
libc.conf
```

And `libc.conf` contains `/usr/local/lib` but `addtheselibraries.conf` contains, e.g. `/usr/lib`,<sup>1</sup> then the latter will take precedence.  If the `/usr/local/lib` file doesn't contain anything else, just rename it with something which will supersede the other files; numbers go first so `000-whatever` is good.

Because you have complete control over `/usr/local/lib`, it *should* take precedence over any paths used by the distro package manager (and usually does).

<sup>1. /usr/lib is a default compiled into the linker, but it and other standard system places (/lib, etc) are added *last*, which allows you to supersede them.  Because of these, sometimes (e.g.) `/usr/lib` is added to a .conf file in order to make it supersede some other .conf file.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

```
openssl version -a
```

The above command will give you the version of openssl in the system. Check the build date rather than the date on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to recompile openssh, by downloading the source including the openssl source in the source tree and run `./config; make; make install` for `openssh` as well.

Detailed instructions on compiling openssh can be found in the [INSTALL document](ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL)

Comment: `ssh` should link to `libssl` and not need to be rebuilt. You can check this with `ldd /usr/bin/ssh`, presuming that's where it is.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' `ldd $(which ssh) | fgrep ssl` gives no output, so the executable (which is in `/usr/bin`)  doesn't seem to be dynamically linked against ssl.

Comment: That seems to be the case on debian, yeah, maybe as a (dubious and in this case ill conceived) security measure. It's dynamically linked on fedora. +1

Comment: Added more information per suggestions.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, your OP does **not** refer to compiling **SSH** at all, only to compiling ssl

Comment: All I am trying to do is apply the bleeding heart bug patch. That's all. Usually, I take the yum updates for my Linux systems. Are you saying I should get latest ssh as well? This patch is for our web sites. The rest of our systems are behind a firewall, and isolated from the Internet by a single point of failure routing system.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus For the bleeding heart bug you shouldn't need to upgrade ssh. If you want your `ssh -V` to show the latest OpenSSL version, **as per your OP**, then you need to recompile (or at least I did need to compile on Ubuntu).

Comment: ssh is the red hearing. I removed that from the OP.